# Twitter authentication iOS

Tags: ios, authentication, twitter

With my app i can share stuff on Facebook G+ and Twitter and it works fine

But i have one problem, with Facebook or G+ i can authenticate myself if i'm not already connected on the FB or G+ app

I would like to do the same for Twitter but i don't know if it's possible, is it ?

this is my code to tweet something :

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {
    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController 
       composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"testing"];
    [tweetSheet addImage:[UIImage imageWithData:myImg]];
    [tweetSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.com"]];

    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"You can't send a tweet right now" 
       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]show];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question looks like this:

[Login with twitter in ios 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202274/login-with-twitter-in-ios-7)

But you can use the Twitter Kit for iOS for the login:

https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/twitter-login

The SDK first attempts to leverage system Twitter accounts, via Accounts.framework. If that fails, it falls back to presenting an OAuth flow. After successful authentication, the SDK automatically saves the account to iOS system accounts and the TWTRSession will contain a token, secret, username, and user ID of the user. If authentication fails, the error will be non-nil